# .net MVC form to upload file and other fields EF

Tags: .net, sql-server, forms, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a .net MVC EF application. I need to create a form to upload a file and other fields into the database (like the file itself and file description, category, etc.). I have a table in a SQL Server database with FileStream (hence the varbinary(max)).

Table:
    `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyDocuments](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [docID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [document] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM NOT NULL,
    [docName] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [docLink] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [docCategory] [text] NULL,
    [docPermission] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [docTeam] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [docAssigmentDate] [date] NULL,
    [docCompletedDate] [date] NULL,
    [docArchivedDate] [date] NULL)`

Model:

```
public partial class MyDocument
{
    public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid docID { get; set; }
    public byte[] document { get; set; }
    public string docName { get; set; }
    public string docLink { get; set; }
    public string docCategory { get; set; }
    public string docPermission { get; set; }
    public string docTeam { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> docAssigmentDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> docCompletedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> docArchivedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I need to have a form that allows the user to enter the information including a browse for a file to upload and submit everything into the database table. So I need help with the Controller and View. Is there a good example code or instructions on how I can do this. Some example would sure be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Whichframework you ask ?  `asp.net-MVC` or `Asp.Net-Core-MVC`, your question is not clear.  upload file  is  irrelevant  to the entityframework, EF is about query/save data to the database,  and upload file is about receive data from browser.

Comment: It's asp.net -MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. your form must use `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>`
2. in your action you need to use `IFormFile yourformfiledname` to receive the data (get the byte array)
3. then you can do you want, you can save it to a file on your server, or you can save it to the database

---

**Sorry, My answer is for Asp.net-Core**
for asp.net , I think you can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.File` to receive the file